# Require all characters of a range

Tags: regex

How can you look for a word which has all characters you need?

For example I have the following regular expression, how can it match the 1st and the 3rd lines, instead of the 1st and 2nd?

```
[abc]+\s
```

To find:

```
abcb # all abc, no other letters
abab # not all abc, no other letters
abcd # all abc, other letters
abdd # not all abc, other letters
```